# O que significam os termos CPU-time e Wall-clock-time?

Tags: terminologia, multithreading, programação-funcional, cpu, clock

Algumas documentações (programação) se referem a estes termos quando há algum tipo de limitação quanto ao uso da CPU, por exemplo:

> As tarefas em segundo plano são limitadas pela quantidade de tempo de
>   uso do *wall-clock*.
>
> *Background tasks* são limitadas a 30 segundos de uso do *wall-clock*.

Sem compreender o que exatamente este termos significam fica difícil adequar um software para que o mesmo não extrapole o uso da CPU recomendado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPU Time é o tempo que o processador gasta para executar uma tarefa.

Wall Clock Time é o tempo todo passado para executar uma tarefa, então se houver interrupções na execução da atividade o *wall clock* não para de contar, mas o tempo de CPU não é considerado.

A interrupção pode ocorrer porque o processador divide seu uso com outras *threads* ou porque precisa esperar um dispositivo externo ao CPU responder ou o algoritmo está em espera sem executar nada.

Isto é uma forma de diferenciar se o limite que pode usar adota um critério ou outro. Se o limite fosse pelo CPU *time* na verdade ele poderia rodar por minutos, horas ou até dias, desde que a maior parte do tempo não esteja executando nada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).